# Microsoft Excel 2013 coloring part of a cell that is a variable

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a cell that has text and within the text there is a variable "&b7&"
Cell B7 is a drop down from a list of items.
Currently when I drop down the items it populates varibale and I can copy and paste out what I want ALMOST perfectly. the issue is I want this variable to be formatted text ( a different color & Bold) no matter what I do to the drop down it always shows with the default forma. It basically makes me format all the text the same.

Answer (score 1):

Excel's support for changing the font or colour of just part of the text in a cell is EXTREMELY limited. You cannot copy text formatting between cells with a formula or reference - abotu the only ways to do it are by manually selecting part of the text and changing it, or by using VBA.

This is because Excel is an analytical and reference application. It's not designed for complex formatting.

Comment: any hints on using VBA to change the colour of part of a cell?